# Unitils with @SpringApplicationContext - The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'

Tags: java, spring, junit, applicationcontext, unitils

I have using maven and i have following dependency to my project.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
        <artifactId>unitils-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
        <artifactId>unitils-dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My Testing Class like it is specify on the [official documentation](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-spring.html)

```
package fr.meehome.user.dao.impl;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4;
import org.unitils.spring.annotation.SpringApplicationContext;
import org.unitils.spring.annotation.SpringBeanByType;

import fr.meehome.user.dao.IUserDao;

@SpringApplicationContext({"/fr/meehome/user/dao/applicationContext-test.xml" })
public class UserDaoTest extends UnitilsJUnit4 {

    @SpringBeanByType
    private IUserDao userDao;

    @Test
    public void dummyTest() {
        Assert.assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

My ApplicationContext file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.meehome.user.dao" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>fr.meehome.user.dao.domain.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

When i run my test, i have this stack trace :

```
org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Unable to create application context for locations [/fr/meehome/user/dao/applicationContext-test.xml]
    at org.unitils.spring.util.ApplicationContextManager.createInstanceForValues(ApplicationContextManager.java:121)
    at org.unitils.spring.util.ApplicationContextManager.createInstanceForValues(ApplicationContextManager.java:36)
    at org.unitils.core.util.AnnotatedInstanceManager.getInstanceImpl(AnnotatedInstanceManager.java:234)
    at org.unitils.core.util.AnnotatedInstanceManager.getInstance(AnnotatedInstanceManager.java:121)
    at org.unitils.spring.util.ApplicationContextManager.getApplicationContext(ApplicationContextManager.java:65)
    at org.unitils.spring.SpringModule.getApplicationContext(SpringModule.java:235)
    at org.unitils.spring.SpringModule$1.isApplicableFor(SpringModule.java:108)
    at org.unitils.database.transaction.impl.DefaultUnitilsTransactionManager.getTransactionManagementConfiguration(DefaultUnitilsTransactionManager.java:180)
    at org.unitils.database.transaction.impl.DefaultUnitilsTransactionManager.startTransaction(DefaultUnitilsTransactionManager.java:96)
    at org.unitils.database.DatabaseModule.startTransaction(DatabaseModule.java:410)
    at org.unitils.database.DatabaseModule.startTransactionForTestMethod(DatabaseModule.java:381)
    at org.unitils.database.DatabaseModule$DatabaseTestListener.beforeTestSetUp(DatabaseModule.java:535)
    at org.unitils.core.Unitils$UnitilsTestListener.beforeTestSetUp(Unitils.java:273)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$TestListenerInvokingMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.access$000(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$1.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 18 in XML document from class path resource [fr/meehome/user/dao/applicationContext-test.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:113)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
    at org.unitils.spring.util.ApplicationContextManager.createInstanceForValues(ApplicationContextManager.java:117)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 40 more
```

I have already see many probleme like this on stackoverflow and the solution is to make a right declaration of xmlns context and schemaLocation. and they are good in this case.

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
```

May be the version org.unitils.spring.annotation.SpringApplicationContext cannot load

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You need to make sure: http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd is on your classpath too

Comment: It was a good idea, in fact i have in my class path the jar : spring-context-2.5.2.jar... I will try to change it for a 3.3.

Comment: Ok it is good now.
I have add to my pom this new dependencies :
`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>  
</dependency>`

Comment: Ok great I added it as an answer so you can close the questions

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure: `springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd` is on your classpath too. If it doesn't come with unitils you can include the Spring dependency directly:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> 
    <version>${spring.version}</version> 
</dependency>
```

Make sure you include the right version for your namespace